# Download Mp3 from online Winamp Flash Player

Tags: audio, flash, mp3

I am listening some songs in online Winamp flash Player. I want to download the all songs from the online Player to my computer. Is there any Browser Plugin or Third party software available to Download the songs ?

Comment: Did you try [these](http://thenextweb.com/apps/2012/05/17/here-are-9-chrome-extensions-that-you-should-try-right-now/) things? [Video](https://www.google.ae/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a83QmTOrQ8Q&ei=YYlPU9m-DfOZ0AXk_oCYCQ&usg=AFQjCNFsPHtVw9-FMoW1orEnbrx1sq5D7w). For more details. What is the web site you are using?

Comment: [Link](http://www.tamilchristianmp3.com/player.php?sec_data=%276678339f33ff08018524ce3e63695c63%27&pf=27&kf=7&sr=2&sec=6678339f33ff08018524ce3e63695c63)
This is the site  I want to download the songs.

Comment: @SmithDwayne After a quick analysis (using the developer console in Chrome), I found out that those requests targeting `getPlayData.php?get=...` contain the actual music data. Now you have to find a way to capture the data sent with those requests. (Chrome's "copy response body" feature strangely cuts off the data after a special character.)

Answer (score 2):

For most websites Firefox with [FlashGot](http://flashgot.net/) will work. When you browse a website that has flash media, an icon will appear in the top right corner. Clicking it will allow you to download any audio-video content. Or you can right-click almost everywhere on the page and choose `FlashGot All`

But not on this one. Right-clicking on the player will show you its name `Secure TS Player`. [This](http://www.tsplayer.com/) is its web page. It seems it is specifically designed to prevent unauthorized downloads:

> SecureTSPlayer is a Flash Music Player software for websites, designed specially for people that need to protect the audio files from unauthorized downloads.
>
> Users can listen to the song, but can not access the playlist, can not download the mp3 file and the file is not accessible for unauthorized downloads. With SecureTSPlayer the audio files are not cached by the browser.

From [http://www.tsplayer.com](http://www.tsplayer.com/)